# Combine a 2D array into 1D without numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

The result of a list comprehension:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'ac', 'bc'], ['abc']]
```

The challenge is to convert this into a single list, on **one line**, importing only **itertools** (if it helps)

Comment: Since most of the standard flattening idioms work fit on one line, I don't think we need a separate question.  Plus, this is Python: we shouldn't care about cramming everything onto one line anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'ac', 'bc'], ['abc']]))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can indicate to future readers that this answer resolved your issue by clicking the "accept" button below its score.